# Popup opening after a long delay (ReactJS performance issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fixing some bugs in a React Application. One of the issue is that the popup opens 12 seconds after clicking on open button. But I am not sure what is causing the issue. There are no network requests in play here. Here is the pseudo code:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    state = { isOpen: false } 
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ isOpen: true})
    }

    // lots of methods

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                // lots of other JSX
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick}
                <Popup visible={this.state.isOpen}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`ComponentA` is actually a pretty big component, and I doubt it might be the reason for the slowness. But considering that React uses virtual DOM, should this still be an issue? 2-3 seconds would still seem like a reasonable time for virtual DOM to calculate the diff even for a large app, but 12 seconds?

EDIT: I took a performance audit in Chrome, recording activity from the moment I click the button to the time the popup appears on screen. Here is the output of that:

[image: Performance Audit]

I am not sure what does `scripting` refers to here. All the parsing of JavaScript, which I believe is generally referred to as `scripting` is done after scripts are downloaded. But here, the `Popup` is opened much after the page has been loaded, and no new scripts are being downloaded on click of `Button`. If `scripting` means `executing` here, then what does `rendering` refer to in above graph?

Comment: If it's caused by virtual DOM calculation you must see CPU usage (1 core not all) suddenly used at 100%, otherwise if it's the networks which take times open your browser inspector, you should see in network panel the concerned request

Comment: Any expensive lifecycle methods running?

Comment: Try this: `this.setState((prevState) => return({ isOpen: true}))` avoids React's batch updates on event handlers.

Comment: @cbdev420 `componentDidMount` calls `setState()` and 3-4 other methods

Comment: @Nicolas I added the performance graph above..

Comment: Instead of only loading the component when `isOpen: true` change it to  `<Popup isOpen={this.state.isOpen}/>` and have the Popup component return null when the isOpen prop is false. This will mean you are only having a component re-render instead of loading a completely new component in to the DOM, which should give better performance.

Comment: @Callum: I already did that but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Damn that's all I could think of without seeing the code, only other thing I can recommend is to use the chrome tools some more and drill into the scripting blocks to see which specific functions are taking so much time.